# .serialize() not working after Ajax has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

I am working for my company on a list of advanced training courses (with different names, locations, ...) and I want to build up the whole admin area on Ajax, so no refresh of the page is needed.

When I use

```
onclick="alert($('#course96').serialize());"
```

to get the contents of the whole HTML form everything works properly.

Once I refresh the content section (the *div* object) with, for example,

```
$("#courses").load("do.php");
```

the value of the serialize()-function is empty. I have looked for a solutions for hours, but without any success. So, can you help me?

EDIT

The (shortened) source of the do.php, which is loaded in the *div* object, is:

```
<form id="kurs<?php echo $row->id; ?>" name="kurs<?php echo $row->id; ?>" method="post">

        <tr>

            <td class="highlighted">
                <input name="kursort" type="text">
            </td>

            (...)

            <td>
                <select name="bis_monat">
                    *<option> generated with PHP*
                </select>
                <select name="bis_jahr">
                    *<option> generated with PHP*
                </select>               
            </td>

            <td  class="edit_light">
                <a onclick="deleteKurs('<?php echo $row->id; ?>')">L&ouml;schen</a>
                <input type="button" value="Speichern" onclick="alert($('#kurs96').serialize());" />    
            </td>

        </tr>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The static div caption *kurs96* in the javascript call is used for testing purposes and will be dynamically later.

Comment: there's quite a bit of detail missing here: some questions I have is: What is the structure of your HTML? (is the event handler ourside #courses?)? Are you sure, there is a #course96 after that reload? Does the alert get triggered after the reload (with an empty message) or does no alert appear at all?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]